# How to find similar images from gallery in iOS SDk?

Tags: ios, image, duplicates, image-gallery, photosframework

I am working on a iOS app which has to find the similar images from the gallery.I worked around and found the way to get the **exact duplicate image** either using any of the following -:

**1. Image hash**

```
              unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

             CC_MD5([imageData bytes], [imageData length], result);

             NSString *imageHash = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                                    result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
                                    result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
                                    result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
                                    result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
                                    ];
```

**2. Image Data**

[ UIImagePNGRepresentation( uiImage1 ) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation( uiImage2 ) ];

**Requirement :**

1. Both ways worked good for the exact duplicate images but we need to find Similar Images say about 90% similarity.
2. To identify both normal image and HDR of the one click as a duplicate image since the hash value and data changes for HDR and normal images they are treated as different images for the both approach above.

**Finding RGB and Comparing Images:**

I have got an idea of finding RGB values of the image and compare which gives 90% similarity between them but this approach seems to be much more time consuming since we have to compare pixel by pixel all images and comparing thousands of images from gallery will be a tedious task.

So what should be **efficient** way to find the duplicate images from gallery including the normal and HDR images and images with similarity as well for apps supporting photos framework.

Comment: please check this https://github.com/aleph7/AIImageCompare might be useful

Comment: @Imran did you find a solution for this?